# Nodejs API Cronjob node-schedule not running inside docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, automation, cron, node-schedule

Created an API to run some scheduled jobs with Nodejs which is running in a docker container.

```
exports.createAutoJobs = async (req, res, next) => {
console.log("Request received")
    cron.schedule('* * * * *', () => {
        console.log('Running');
    });
}
```

The above code is printing "Running" for every minute
But for the same code adding a custom time pattern is not working

```
exports.createAutoJobs = async (req, res, next) => {
console.log("Request received")
    cron.schedule('00 13 15 * *', () => {
        console.log('Running');
    });
}
```

The custom pattern is working if it is outside the container as a normal Nodejs application, but not inside the docker container.
What is the way to get around it and run the cron jobs inside a docker container. Is there an alternative to this approach?

Comment: Faced the same problem, RecurrenceRule behave the same

Comment: what Docker image are you using as a base?

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was the **base image**. I used `node:18-slim`. After switching to `node:18-alpine` and checking **container timezone** (mounted a file with a time zone to my container) the problem was solved.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! In my case I just need to add the proper timezone that is all.